# How to get status of compilation = enabled or disabled?

Tags: magento, compilation

I have a module that uses a library when compiling is active the url changes and can not find the library

I want something like this $ this-> getCompilation () that returns enabled or disabled

So I can make a condition in class to change the url library call when the build is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If it returns 1 when execute `echo defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH');` means compilation is enabled. It returns empty when it is disabled.